# Query item detail based on previous query result DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Im still new with DynamoDB , How do I query something based on the previous query result?

This is how my table look like :

[image]

I want to query for the list of project info for an user.
From my first query , the result of USER#001 have [PROJECT#001,PROJECT#002].
Then I want to get a list project detail based on the first query.
How do I make an "nested" query ?? or is there anyway there I can query more efficiently ?

*The table structure is fix, I cant change it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  That's not the way DDB works...

All you could do is a [BatchGetItem()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) with the pk & sk for the two projects.

Or if you don't happen to know the SK, you'd need to make two individual Query() calls with the pk only.